# Web Platform Installer - Customize Web Application Installation UI

Tags: iis, web-applications, web-platform-installer

I am trying to realize a web application which can be deployed through the Microsoft Web Platform Installer for a private usage (i don't want to publish my application, so i made a custom feed). 
I can deploy my web application on my IIS through the Web Platform Installer but not in the way I want because I can't manage to tweak the installation UI.

I created a paramaters.xml in my project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
<parameter name="Paramètre 1" description="Blablabla" defaultValue="MySite/MyApplication" tags="IisApp">
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="iisApp" match="MySite/MyApplication" />
</parameter>
<parameter name="Paramètre 2" description="Blablabla" defaultValue="MySite" tags="AppHostConfig">
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="appHostConfig" match="MySite" />
</parameter>
<parameter name="Paramètre 4" description="Blablabla" defaultValue="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\MyApplication" tags="PhysicalPath">
    <parameterEntry kind="DestinationVirtualDirectory" scope="MySite/MyApplication/" match="" />
</parameter>
<parameter name="Paramètre 5" description="Blablabla" defaultValue="MyAppPool" tags="AppPoolConfig">
    <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="appPoolConfig" match="MyAppPool" />
</parameter>
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: what's your particular problem?

Comment: I want to tweak this part of the installation with my parameters : [link](http://media.jamesrskemp.com/graphics/windowsServer2003/webPlatformInstaller_WordPress_08.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't put the manifest.xml file into my package so the configuration screen wasn't appearing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MSDeploy.iisApp>
<iisapp path="application" />
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

Although, you must activate the configuration of the whole parameters of the web application in the option of the Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Web PI automatically load your custom feed. However, you can automate the process with [WebPICmdLine tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433092.aspx).